# Spacing around gather when math color is given

Tags: beamer, spacing, align

I am trying to get rid of the spacing around gather/align environments in a Beamer presentation. As usual, I set the `abovedisplayskip` & friends registers to zero with `\g@addto@macro\normalsize`. This works great (uncomment lua-visual-debug to show the debug lines in LuaLaTeX):

```
\documentclass[xcolor=dvipsnames,compress,9pt]{beamer}
\usepackage{amsmath}
%\usepackage{lua-visual-debug}

\mode<presentation>
\usenavigationsymbolstemplate{}

\setlength{\parskip}{0.2cm plus 1fill}
\global\parskip=\parskip
\makeatletter
\g@addto@macro\normalsize{%
  \setlength\abovedisplayskip{0cm plus 0cm minus 0cm}
  \setlength\belowdisplayskip{0cm plus 0cm minus 0cm}
  \setlength\abovedisplayshortskip{0cm plus 0cm minus 0cm}
  \setlength\belowdisplayshortskip{0cm plus 0cm minus 0cm}
}

\define@key{beamerframe}{c}[true]{% centered
    \beamer@frametopskip=0pt plus 1fill
    \beamer@framebottomskip=0pt plus 1fill%
    \beamer@frametopskipautobreak=0pt plus .4\paperheight\relax%
    \beamer@framebottomskipautobreak=0pt plus .6\paperheight\relax%
    \def\beamer@initfirstlineunskip{}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus
 elit,
    vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida
mauris.
\par
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit,
vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida
mauris.
\par
\begin{gather*}
x^2+y^2=z^2
\end{gather*}
\par
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit,
vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida
mauris.
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

So far so good!

Unexpectedly, additional space is introduced if I set the `math text` Beamer color:

```
\documentclass[xcolor=dvipsnames,compress,9pt]{beamer}
\usepackage{amsmath}
%\usepackage{lua-visual-debug}

\mode<presentation>
\usenavigationsymbolstemplate{}

\setlength{\parskip}{0.2cm plus 1fill}
\global\parskip=\parskip
\makeatletter
\g@addto@macro\normalsize{%
  \setlength\abovedisplayskip{0cm plus 0cm minus 0cm}
  \setlength\belowdisplayskip{0cm plus 0cm minus 0cm}
  \setlength\abovedisplayshortskip{0cm plus 0cm minus 0cm}
  \setlength\belowdisplayshortskip{0cm plus 0cm minus 0cm}
}

\define@key{beamerframe}{c}[true]{% centered
    \beamer@frametopskip=0pt plus 1fill
    \beamer@framebottomskip=0pt plus 1fill%
    \beamer@frametopskipautobreak=0pt plus .4\paperheight\relax%
    \beamer@framebottomskipautobreak=0pt plus .6\paperheight\relax%
    \def\beamer@initfirstlineunskip{}%
}
\makeatother
\setbeamercolor{math text}{fg=red} %%% HERE!

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus
 elit,
    vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida
mauris.
\par
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit,
vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida
mauris.
\par
\begin{gather*}
x^2+y^2=z^2
\end{gather*}
\par
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit,
vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida
mauris.
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Is there any way I can use the `math text` feature without losing my beloved spacing configuration? My guess is that, when starting math mode, Beagle's template for math formatting is triggered and the values of `abovedisplayskip` & friends are reseted.

Comment: I don't understand why you reset the skip via normalsize. If you want them to be zero, then why not globally? Beside this the problem is the grouping from the color along with the \par you are using before and after the gather.

Comment: related: https://bitbucket.org/rivanvx/beamer/issues/177/setbeamercolor-math-text-enlarges-spacing

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I tried via `\global\abovedisplayskip=0pt` and so on, with the same results. Regarding the `\par`s, I actually want equations as standalone paragraphs. Any idea how could I redefine the displayskips after the color has been set?

Comment: @samcarter yes, that sounds as essentially the same problem. Still, it is suggested in that thread that this is an intended feature in Beamer.

Comment: link to the above mentioned issue changed to https://github.com/josephwright/beamer/issues/177