# Odd spacing in beamer's display math with everydisplay and color

Tags: beamer, math-mode, color

Using `\only<2>{\everydisplay{\color{blue}}}` colors math as expected, but changes the spacing of display maths. What's happening?

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\only<2>{\everydisplay{\color{blue}}}

\[ \frac{2}{a} \]

\[ \frac{2}{a} \]
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Output from both slides, side-by-side:[image: output]

Comment: `\setbeamercolor{math text displayed}{fg=red}` has the same problem

Comment: Would `\[\textcolor<2>{red}{\frac{2}{a}}\]%` be an acceptable workaround?

Comment: @samcarter That workaround is functional but I remain curious about this behavior. Using `\setbeamercolor{math text displayed}{fg=red}` seems to change the spacing to the new one but it remains the same through the slides.

Comment: Yes, it seems applying colour changes the spacing.

Comment: maybe this is helpful: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/91536/579

Comment: related question: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/309567/spacing-around-gather-when-math-color-is-given

Comment: see the footnote in the documentation of the color package, color will sometimes affect spacing. the footnote is there basically to explain that **it's not my fault**  (`texdoc grfguide` page 6 :-) (@samcarter)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To understand the behaviour, the following quick example is useful

```
\[\color{red}\frac{2}{a}\]
\[{\color{red}\frac{2}{a}}\]
```

The first line shows the bigger spacing, the second line is surrounded by an additional group and has tighter spacing. To cite the related [comment of David Carlisle](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/348611/odd-spacing-in-beamers-display-math-with-everydisplay-and-color#comment855960_348611)

> see the footnote in the documentation of the color package, color will sometimes affect spacing. the footnote is there basically to explain that it's not my fault (`texdoc grfguide` page 6 :-)

`\everydisplay{\color{blue}}` clearly adds a `\color` to the math display and triggers this behaviour. `\setbeamercolor{math text displayed}{fg=red}` also triggers it, as normally the math is colour is not set and `\color` is will only be added to the math display if the colour is not empty (see https://github.com/josephwright/beamer/issues/177)

**Solution 1**

To get a uniform behaviour and prevent the jumping between the slides, you can set the math colour at the beginning of the document. This will give all math displays the larger spacing.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\setbeamercolor{math text displayed}{parent=normal text}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\only<2>{\everydisplay{\color{blue}}}

\[ \frac{2}{a} \]
\[ \frac{2}{a} \]
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

---

**Solution 2**

Or if you prefer the tight spacing, the following is based on https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/91551/36296

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\setbeamercolor{mymath}{parent=normal text}

\def\foo#1$$#2!!{\def\mathdisplay##1{#1$$\begingroup\usebeamercolor[fg]{mymath}#2}}
\expandafter\foo\mathdisplay{#1}!!

\long\def\foo#1$$#2!!{\def\endmathdisplay##1{#1\endgroup$$#2}}
\expandafter\foo\endmathdisplay{#1}!!



\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\only<2>{\setbeamercolor{mymath}{fg=red}}
\[ \frac{2}{a} \]
\[ \frac{2}{a} \]
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```