# Bigger space after itemize/enumerate

Tags: beamer, enumerate

In the following MWE, the space after enumerate is not the same when I use overlay specification (too big in this case) or when I use a standard enumerate.
This problem seems to appear only if the last item finishes with math mode.
Any idea to this strange problem ?

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usetheme{Madrid}
\setbeamercovered{transparent}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \begin{enumerate}[<+->]
        \item First item
        \item Second item with math mode :
            $$\forall x,\exists y$$    %% Big space after this
    \end{enumerate}
    After enumerate
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item First item
        \item Second item with math mode :
            $$\forall x,\exists y$$    %% Standard space after this
    \end{enumerate}
    After enumerate
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Off topic: [Why is \[ … \] preferable to $$ … $$?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/503/105447).

Comment: Good question, but hard to solve. It basically boils down to the same problem as https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/309567/spacing-around-gather-when-math-color-is-given . If you use overlays colour is used to gray out the upcoming items. And using colour for math results in the strange space, this is documented in the color package.

Comment: related thread: https://github.com/josephwright/beamer/issues/177

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The underlying problem is the same as in [Spacing around gather when math color is given](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/309567/spacing-around-gather-when-math-color-is-given): Colour in math mode influences the spacing. This behaviour is known (documented in the graphics package documentation, footnote 2) but hard to circumvent.

A little improvement could be to use `\setbeamercolor{math text}{fg=black}`. This will add the additional space to all equations, but at least the spaces will be independent of overlays applied or not and offers a stable base to manually correct the spaces where necessary.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usetheme{Madrid}
\setbeamercovered{transparent}
\setbeamercolor{math text}{fg=black} 

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \begin{enumerate}[<+->]%
        \item First item%
        \item Second item with math mode :%
            \[\forall x,\exists y\]%    %% Big space after this
    \end{enumerate}%
    \vspace*{-\baselineskip}
    After enumerate
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item First item
        \item Second item with math mode :
            \[\forall x,\exists y\]    %% Standard space after this
    \end{enumerate}
    \vspace*{-\baselineskip}
    After enumerate
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you. The height difference seems to be about -1.27\baselineskip (!!).